# How many times function is called to get factorial

Tags: algorithm

How many times fact(n) will be called if n is 8 and fact(n) is a recursive implementation for finding factorial of a number?

Comment: Whatever languages you are using, adding a simple debugging print can give you the answer.

Comment: I think a simple counter won't satisfy your homework ;) ... maybe you can start by adding the definition you are using (where do you check your break-contition? What is it (`n>=2`, `n==1`, ...) - then start and draw yourself a diagram and then start to argue about your code ...

Comment: It depends upon your implementation of the `fact(n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your program looks like

```
public static int fact(int n) {
   if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
       return 1;
   } else {
       return n * fact(n - 1);
   }
}
```

Let's see...

1. n=8 fact(n) get's called which will go into else and
2. with n=7 fact(n) will get called again go to else
3. with n=6 fact(n) will get called
4. with n=5
5. with n=4
6. with n=3
7. with n=2
8. with n=1

So, here it will get called 8 times.